# Can't see phpmyadmin database on my localhost [MacOS]

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I imported a MySQL database (.sql file) to phpmyadmin on MAMP, so i can reach all tables and records on phpmyadmin UI via browser but I can not see this database on my terminal and other database applications. While I can see the databases that I created before but I cannot see that database which created on phpmyadmin. I have checked port number and other connection credentials too many times.

I have already searched this problem on web but couldn't find a working solution.

Any kind of help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If you can see the data in phpmyadmin, but not in other clients, then your phpmyadmin and the other clients either connect to different mysql instances or they use different user ids to access the data. There are no alternative explanations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm sure that I connected with same used ids but probably I connected to two different MySQL instances. If I do the installation from the beginning after deleting and reinstalling, will the problem be fixed? Or do you have any other solution suggestions?

Comment: How do you imagine the issue of separate mysql instances could be resolved by reinstalling one of the instances? You should only have one instance only.

Comment: Anyway, I gave up dealing with this kind of thing and gonna handle database processes by DataGrip. I'm done with that. No more unnecessary actions. Thank you @Shadow